# SAS Dynamic Output Save Files

Tags: dynamic, graph, save, sas, output

I am using proc template and sgrender and outputting ODS based on a class variable (classVar).  I need the output title to update with each graph with the name of the class variable.  Here is an example of my code:

```
proc template;
  define statgraph heatmapparm;
  dynamic _BYVAL_;
    begingraph;
      entrytitle _BYVAL_;
      layout overlay;
        heatmapparm x=X_VAR y=Y_VAR colorresponse=percent / colormodel=(blue yellow red)
          name="heatmapparm" xbinaxis=false ybinaxis=false datatransparency=.5;
        continuouslegend "heatmapparm" / location=outside valign=bottom;
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=roundFreq template=heatmapparm;
    by situation;
run;
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in SAS 9.3+ I believe. What version of SAS do you have?

```
proc template;
define statgraph scatter;
dynamic _x _y _byval_;

 begingraph;
 entrytitle "Scatter Plot of " _x " by " _y " for Sex = " _byval_;
   layout overlay;
     scatterplot x=_x y=_y;
   endlayout;
 endgraph;
end;

run;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex;
run;

proc sgrender data=class
          template=scatter;
 by sex;
dynamic _x='height' _y='weight';
run;
```

Comment: Yes I actually figured this out slightly before you replied.  Using the combination of dynamic and _byval_ worked perfect.  Thank you!